# Eror in SQL syntax: Update query

Tags: php, mysql

I am a beginner to PHP and I am working on a profile page. The current problem is to change the name (This is a trial page that's why i am changing the name).For some reason i am getting the error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'lastName ='Lname' WHERE email ='qwerty@example.com'' at line 1.

```html
<?php
 include('server.php');
 $db = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','userdata');
 $query = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE email = '".$_SESSION['username']."'";
 $result = mysqli_query($db,$query);
 $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
?>
<html> 
 <head> 
  <title>Profile</title>  
 </head>
 <body>
  <form method="POST" action=""> 
   <p>First name: <input type="text" name="fname" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($data['firstName']); ?>" > </p>
   <p>Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($data['lastName']); ?>"> </p>
   <p><input type="Submit" name="confirm" value="Confirm"></p>
  </form>
  <?php
   if(isset($_POST['confirm']))
   {
    $db = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','userdata');
    $query = "UPDATE data SET firstName ='".$_POST['fname']."' lastName ='".$_POST['lname']."'  WHERE email ='".$_SESSION['username']."'";
    mysqli_query($db,$query);
    echo mysqli_error($db); //For checking error.Remove afterwords.
   }
  ?>
  <p><a href="homepage.php">HOMEPAGE</a></p>
 </body> 
</html>
```

The server.php is a page where I manage the backend of the entire operation so it's not involved in this operation.The first PHP block takes data from the table. The HTML block creates a form where the user can edit the data. The PHP block should update data into the table.

I would appreciate any tips to further improve my page as i am still new to this.Thanks in advance

UPDATE:- Adding , to the query still does not change the situation.

Comment: You need a comma between the update fields e.g. `UPDATE data set field1="meh", field2="foo" where otherField="something"`

Comment: I tried that but t still gave the same error

Comment: Try not to include $_POST or any input variable in your query. Look for pdo and mysql parametrized queries.

Comment: Can you echo `$query` and post it here?

Comment: you really should not writre code like that .... so bad

Answer (score 1):

you have an error in your sql statement (as the error message suggests). in mysql the error message usually points out the exact position where the error occurs, and it usually quotes the first character/word that causes the problem.

in your case, that's `lastname`. Your update query so far is:

```
UPDATE data SET firstName ='fname' lastName ='Lname' WHERE email ='qwerty@example.com'
--                                 ^ error occured here
```

when you look-up how UPDATE queries are supposed to look like (mysql docs) you'd find, that the different updated fields must be separated by comma:

```
UPDATE data SET firstName ='fname', lastName ='Lname' WHERE email ='qwerty@example.com'
--                                ^ add this here
```

also, you're vulnerable to sql injections (please read up on them, and how to prevent them - this is done by prepared statements)

Comment: Thanks. I will read about sql injections but adding commas still does not change the error

Comment: I challenge you, that it does change the error *message*. You should have a different error now.

Comment: It did not change. That's the reason why I asked

Comment: @PrateekMehta is it possible you're changing the wrong file?

Answer (score 0):

Please try with that(there was a missing comma on your SQL query).

```
$query = "UPDATE data SET firstName ='".$_POST['fname']."', lastName ='".$_POST['lname']."'  WHERE email ='".$_SESSION['username']."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

The other problem of using code that is open to sql injection is you can easily change the syntax of an sql statement from the input side. For example if for last name you input "O'connor", you change the syntax. Try to use `echo $query` and then analyse the output or better still,copy it and run it directly without using php

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned in the comment. When updating multiple fields you need to comma separate them:

```
UPDATE data 
set 
field1="meh", /* <-- comma */
field2="foo" 
where otherField="something"
```